# Android - take a custom string

Tags: java, android, string, substring

I have a file path name whose prefix always changes as below :

```
"Unregistered_2018-05-02_14.40.04_+621241411112_34243555523.mp3"
"Martin_2018-04-01_03.10.40_+111_5213441935.mp3"
"Byan_2018-01-04_04.70.01_+62994_2313325553.mp3"
```

How can I retrieve date `(2018-01-04)`, time `(04.70.01)` and number phone `(+111)` with the ever-changing data ?

Whoever you are I am very grateful to finish this

Comment: just split with `_` then take the `split[1], split[2], split[3]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use split with `_` like this :

```
String[] texts = new String[] {
        "Unregistered_2018-05-02_14.40.04_+621241411112_34243555523.mp3",
        "Martin_2018-04-01_03.10.40_+111_5213441935.mp3",
        "Byan_2018-01-04_04.70.01_+62994_2313325553.mp3",
};
for (String text : texts) {
    String[] split = text.split("_");
    String date  = split[1];
    String time  = split[2];
    String phone = split[3];

    System.out.println("date = " + date + ", time = " + time + ", phone = " + phone);
}
```

Outputs

```
date = 2018-05-02, time = 14.40.04, phone = +621241411112
date = 2018-04-01, time = 03.10.40, phone = +111
date = 2018-01-04, time = 04.70.01, phone = +62994
```

Comment: Oh sorry, I want to take a 'name' too. how is that? maybe i will not add '_' at the front, because this is for search filter

Comment: Solved, thnks brother

Comment: @MuhammadImanudin sorry I was sleeping, about the name you can use  `String name = split[0];` I don't understand the second part